# Please recommend a jQuery menu plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Could someone recommend a jQuery menu plugin, looks like the picture below. I need to open all tabs by default, but also can collapse a tab on demand.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This should be exactly what you need: (only the colors are different :D)

http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/jquery-accordion-menu/index_collapsed.html#
[image]

Comment: Nice Adnan!  That is very simple

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the JQuery UI plugin library?  You can create *many* different UI effects with it, including a vertical menu (browse effects and look under "accordion").  The URL is: http://jqueryui.com/

Two other notes: learning it gives you a real advantage for your resume and JQueryUI will give you the option of customizing the package before the download so it fits with your current graphical scheme.

Answer (score 0):

I like Brothercake.  They supply an assortment of accessible drop down menu's tooltips etc.  A bonus of all their design patterns is that they are marked up to ensure that a persons with disabilities (screen reader's, low vision, etc) can easily use their widgets and tools.  Have a look!

[BrotherCake](http://www.brothercake.com/scripts/listmenu/)